# Changing af string into a list of tuples with values

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a string like this:

```
'(459..521),(1834..2736)'
```

and I want to make it look like this:

```
[(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]
```

That is, a list of tuples with values, not strings.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
def parseAnnotation(annotation):
thing=[]
number=""
for c in annotation:
    if c.isdigit()==True:
        number=number+c
    else:
        thing.append(number)
        number=""
thing.append(number)
thing = filter(None, thing)
return thing
```

Output:

```
['459', '521', '1834', '2736']
```

I have af feeling, that I've taken a longer road than necessary, so inputs to an easier approach are much welcome. Please bear with me, I am very new to Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
def parseAnnotation(annotation):
    return [tuple(pair[1:-1].split('..')) for pair in annotation.split(',')]
```

Edit: `literal_eval` is slower (and less pythonic IMO):

```
In [4]: %timeit list(ast.literal_eval(strs.replace('..',',')))
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit [tuple(pair[1:-1].split('..')) for pair in strs.split(',')]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 us per loop
```

Another edit: forgot that you need `ints`.

```
def parseAnnotation(annotation):
    return [tuple(map(int, pair[1:-1].split('..'))) for pair in annotation.split(',')]
```

This is getting a little unreadable, let's write this as a loop:

```
def parseAnnotation(annotation):
    result = []
    for pair in annotation.split(','):
        a, b = pair[1:-1].split('..')
        result.append( (int(a), int(b)) )
    return result
```

You decide if it needs to deal with invalid inputs.

Comment: I still get strings, when I write your function? This that right?

Comment: This last edit is really nice - fits my level as well. (started programming 7 weeks ago)

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
annotation = '(459..521),(1834..2736)'

def parseAnnotation(annotation):
    return list(ast.literal_eval(annotation.replace('..', ',')))

# returns [(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]
```

Comment: AST is a huge overkill for this. Also it will throw `SyntaxError`s with invalid inputs, something you wouldn't want to catch.

Comment: Also I did not know the function before this comment, so I might not use this one, since it is a bit out of my curriculum. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
In [9]: import ast

In [11]: strs='(459..521),(1834..2736)'

In [12]: strs=strs.replace("..",",")

In [13]: lis=ast.literal_eval(strs)

In [14]: lis
Out[14]: ((459, 521), (1834, 2736))

In [16]: list(lis)
Out[16]: [(459, 521), (1834, 2736)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here I go with a ast-less answer (ast is not in my cv for now)

```
s = '(459..521),(1834..2736)'
result = []
for x in s.split(','):
    x = x.strip('()')
    x = x.split('..')
    x = [int(i) for i in x]
    result.append(tuple(x))
print result
```

Always try to get the pattern in the string and play a little with the strings methods.

Comment: Although when smart people advice you to use something it may be for some reason, I would go with ast, is worth the learning, and is made for this situations.